# Is there a way to use the GitLab "Merge when pipeline succeeds" together with Review apps (that need an auto-stop job)?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline with [review apps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/). So when the pipeline runs in the context of a Merge Request / Pull Request then I run:

- build and upload a docker image to ECR tagged with `$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID`
- deploy a helm chart that configures the app to be visible at `$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID.reviewapps.example.com`

I want to delete that docker image tag and kubernetes deployment after the merge request is merged/closed, so I added the following `stop review app` job:

```
deploy review app:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine/helm:3.5.0
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - helm -n "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" upgrade
      --install --wait "$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID" chart
      -f helm-reviewapp-values.yaml
      --set-string "ingress.annotations.external-dns\.alpha\.kubernetes\.io/hostname=$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID.reviewapps.example.com."
      --set-string "ingress.host=$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID.reviewapps.example.com"
      --set-string "image=$AWS_REPOSITORY:$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID"
      --set "deploymentAnnotations.app\.gitlab\.com/app=${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}"
      --set "deploymentAnnotations.app\.gitlab\.com/env=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}"
      --set "podAnnotations.app\.gitlab\.com/app=${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}"
      --set "podAnnotations.app\.gitlab\.com/env=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}"

  environment:
    name: review/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    url: https://$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID.reviewapps.example.com
    on_stop: stop review app
    auto_stop_in: 1 day
  needs:
    - build docker image review app
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

stop review app:
  stage: cleanup approval
  script: echo approved
  dependencies: []
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    action: stop
  needs:
    - deploy review app
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

uninstall helm chart:
  stage: cleanup
  image: alpine/helm:3.5.0
  dependencies: []
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    action: stop
  script:
    - helm -n "$KUBE_NAMESPACE" uninstall "$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID"
  needs:
    - stop review app
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      allow_failure: true

delete ecr image:
  stage: cleanup
  image: amazon/aws-cli:2.1.19
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name XXXX --image-ids "imageTag=$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID"
  needs:
    - stop review app
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      allow_failure: true
```

As you can see the `stop review job` is

- referred in the "deploy review app" in the `environment:on_stop`, making use of the [environment auto-stop feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#environments-auto-stop)
- marked as `when:manual`
- made optional with `allow_failure: true`

Then the pipeline looks like this

the `stop review app` still "blocks" the pipeline, it shows as `running` until the stop job runs:

[image: gitlab pipeline]

This is bothering me because when people click on the [Merge when pipeline succeeds](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_when_pipeline_succeeds.html) nothing will really happen until the environment is manually stopped (by clicking the play button on the `stop review app` job).

I also tried removing the `allow_failure` from the stop job but the only difference is that the pipeline will be stuck in state `blocked` instead of `running`.

Is there a way to use the `Merge when pipeline succeeds` together with Review apps (that need a stop job)?

Answer (score 1):

This caused by the `needs: stop review app` in the downstream jobs.

As a workaround you can create a **single** job that performs all the cleanup instead of having `uninstall helm chart` and `delete ecr image` depending on `stop review app` via `needs:`.

You will need to use a docker image for the job that has all the tools required (`helm` and `aws-cli` in your case).

The following pipeline `.gitlab-ci.yml` will turn to **`passed`** after `deploy review app` passed. The single optional stop job `stop review app` does not force the pipeline to remain in `running` or `blocked` and the pipeline succeeds without having to run that particular job:

```
stages:
  - test
  - package
  - deploy
  - cleanup approval
  - cleanup


build docker image review app:
  stage: package
  script:
    - echo hello
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

deploy review app:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine/helm:3.5.0
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - echo hello
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    url: https://$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID.reviewapps.tdhb2bdev.com
    on_stop: stop review app
    auto_stop_in: 1 day
  needs:
    - build docker image review app
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

stop review app:
  stage: cleanup approval
  script: 
    - echo helm uninstall xxxx
    - echo aws ecr batch-delete-image xxxx
  dependencies: []
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    action: stop
  needs:
    - deploy review app
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
```